# Spring 3 HTTP Status 404

Tags: eclipse, spring

I use Spring Tool Suite to develop a simple Spring 3 in eclipse. But when i run, "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/hxj/) is not available" is return.

In the console of eclipse: there is no error but some information looks wierd:

```
Jun 29, 2013 7:50:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(H:\My Documents\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core 
\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Spring\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar) - jar not loaded. 

Jun 29, 2013 7:50:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(H:\My Documents\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core 
\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Spring\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded.
```

Following are my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listene-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And the main part of java class: HomeController.java

```
package com.hxj.hxj;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat 
               = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,  DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}

}
```

the servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org
        /schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    /spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema
/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />


<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hxj.hxj" />

</beans:beans>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work because it is a spring MVC project from spring templete project. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks very much!
Eve

Edit:
 Besides, why the url is: localhost:8080/hxj/ 
instead of:     localhost:8080/hxj/home.jsp (or /home.do)?

Thanks

Comment: Try making, in web.xml: `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>` instead of `*.do`.

Comment: I changed it but still got the error with warning: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hxj/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'. But I defined the appServlet in web.xml already. Any sugestion? Thanks @acdcjunior

Answer (score 2):

Acdcjunior is rigth in his comment:

Try making, in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
     <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

instead of *.do.

---

You asked:

Besides, why the url is: localhost:8080/hxj/ instead of: localhost:8080/hxj/home.jsp (or /home.do)?

I expect that the right URL is: `localhost:8080/hxj/home`
(`localhost:8080/hxj/` works only because the welcome URL mapping in the web.XML)

That is because that is the request mapping you specified for the controller method. It is not *.jsp because in Spring you use the url to specify which controller method should be invoked, but not the jsp directly. (And it is not *.do because this is not struts)

Comment: I modified it but I still get this error with warning: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hxj/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'. But I have defined the appServlet in web.xml. @Ralph

Comment: Add some println statement to the Home Controller method. Is it printed when you request the url?

Answer (score 0):

in file HomeController.java try

```
package com.hxj.hxj;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat 
           = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,  DateFormat.LONG, locale);

String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

return "home";
}
}
```

in your src\main\webapp put the redirect.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("home"); %>
```

in web.xml add welcome-file-list

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping> 
   <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

make sure that file home.jsp in /WEB-INF/views/ directory